# index 0 beyond bounds for empty array parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to parse a list of objects that the current user has created to a custom table view from Parse.com. I'm getting this error when I run it:

```
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array
```

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
@interface ProfileViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) PFQuery *query;

@end

@implementation DailyProfileViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self refresh];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    _projects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
}

- (void)refresh {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Projects"];
    [query includeKey:@"user"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *posts, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            [_projects setArray:posts];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            NSLog(@"%@", posts);
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"Fetch posts error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        return;

    }];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _projects.count;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 65;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    _project = [_projects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    ProfileProjectTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ProfileProjectTableViewCell"];

        if (!_user) _user = [PFUser currentUser];

        cell.item = _project;

        [(PFFile*)_project[@"profilePic"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            cell.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }];

        [(PFFile*)_project[@"bgImage"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            cell.bgView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }];

        cell.projectName.text = _project[@"name"];

        return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your viewDidLoad like this..

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
_projects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self refresh];
```

you should call refresh method after intializing array and make sure that the data you are adding should not empty

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `- refresh` before initialising your array? Change your `-viewDidLoad` as such:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    _projects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self refresh];
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `posts` to see if it is empty? Also, is there any reason you are using `initWithCapacity:`? You won't get that error if you use the standard initialiser -- `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`.